# wxPython: Eliminate DC background flicker while moving shapes on a bitmap

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, gdi

I'm trying to create a panel on wxPython with a user-specified bitmap on the background, where a number of shapes can be dragged.

The expected behaviour is:

- User selects an image file on an open file dialog before the panel is initialised;
- The image becomes the background of the panel and is scaled to fit the panel while keeping an aspect ratio that depends on a previous user input;
- A few circles appear over the image and can be dragged by the user.

I've been able to implement this with no functional problems, but I've been having some trouble with background flicker and so far, the solution I've found that results in the smallest amount of flickering is:

- Create a BufferedDC from the loaded image when the panel is created;
- Create a PaintDC inside the EVT_PAINT handler;
- StretchBlit the BufferedDC into the PaintDC;
- Draw the circles on the PaintDC;
- Refresh the panel on any event that changes the circles' position or visibility.

Since the circles are draggable, one of these events is mouse motion, so the panel is refreshed every time the mouse moves over the panel, causing flickering.

How can I implement this behaviour in a way that eliminates background flicker?

Comment: Can you add code example? It will be much easier to help you.

Comment: why dont you just remove the object thats clicked and then make a new panel with the object that the user is dragging and only repaint it back into the DC when you release the drag or whatever

Comment: How about when dragging, show e.g. a circle or outline that moves with the mouse, but only redraw the full picture after the mouse hasn't moved for e.g. 0.2s?

Comment: @barny - You mean a circle or outline that's not part of the PaintDC? As in an independent object that would move with the mouse?

Comment: Yes - show something easy/quick to draw which tells the user they are dragging, and if they pause only then do the expensive draw of the full object/picture

Comment: Just so it's registered here, I ended up doing something else, I lowered the refresh rate. I set up a counter variable incremented by the mouse motion event when a shape is being dragged, and I'm making it only refresh when `counter % n == 0`, n being some number that's an adequate trade-off between flicker and refresh rate.